# iOS Simulator won't work with Xcode 7.3.1 after install macOS and Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode7, macos-sierra

After install macOS Sierra + Xcode 8 beta

My Xcode 7.3.1 can't run iOS simulator anymore,

How can i fixed this?

here is system logs.

```
Jun 15 07:46:11 Siams-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[2246]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimu[2246]
Jun 15 07:46:12 Siams-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[2748]: com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService 209.19 starting.
Jun 15 07:46:12 Siams-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[2748]: Default device D340C405-CF9F-482C-82CE-ADE8A2399529 is no longer in the set, and an alternative could not be found.  iPhone / Watch pairings may not be correct.
Jun 15 07:46:12 Siams-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[2748]: Default device C3CBAFAD-D139-49CE-9EF1-E2437A2349A7 is no longer in the set, and an alternative could not be found.  iPhone / Watch pairings may not be correct.
Jun 15 07:46:12 Siams-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[2748]: Default device 0916CCBC-1DAA-4CA4-8DCA-FFD87C8941E0 is no longer in the set, and an alternative could not be found.  iPhone / Watch pairings may not be correct.
Jun 15 07:46:12 Siams-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[2748]: Default device 9CC780B5-3034-4083-B52F-2354FB0A8252 is no longer in the set, and an alternative could not be found.  iPhone / Watch pairings may not be correct.
```

Another log

```
Jun 15 10:03:26 Siams-MacBook-Pro DTServiceHub[11482]: DTServiceHub[11482]: [error] 'mach_msg_send' failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (268435459)
Jun 15 10:03:36 Siams-MacBook-Pro Xcode[10188]: +[DTServiceHubClient localConnectionWithAuthorization:returningServerPid:]: failed to establish connection with DTServiceHub service '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Resources/DTServiceHub'
Jun 15 10:03:36 Siams-MacBook-Pro Xcode[10188]: Xcode[10188]: [error] 'mach_msg_send' failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (268435459)
```

Comment: Check that you have installed all the relevant updates for XCode

Comment: Yes, It work well before install Sierra.

Comment: It worked for me to re-install XCode by downloading it from https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode "DTAssetProviderService could not start.." error, How fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828996/xcode-dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-error-how-fix-this)

Answer (score 1):

**Short term solution:**

- Build app
- The app will still install on the simulator, even with the error
- Launch the app manually on the simulator
- Go to Xcode
- Click Debug > Attach to Process > Your App Name

This isn't recommended since you have to do it every time you want to run your app.

**Long term solution (recommended):**

Reinstall Xcode from the Developer Center. Doing so will clear this error, and the app will run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

1. Build app
2. The app will still install on the simulator, even with the error
3. Launch the app manually on the simulator
4. Go to Xcode
5. Click Debug > Attach to Process > Your App Name

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by deleting both XCode 7.3.1 and 8 Beta and reinstalling **just** XCode 7.3.1 from DMG.