# How to fix Xcode "DTAssetProviderService could not start.." error?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have upgraded macOS Sierra Developer Preview, but my **Xcode 7.3.1** gives below error while try to run my project on simulator. In addition Generic to archieve gives another error like:

> In addition for archive: a cryptographic verification failure has occured.

[image]

How can I fix this?

I have tried before Xcode 8.0 Beta, uninstall it deleting derivedData and reset content simulator but still occurs this error.

**Update:**

I want to share an information who want to use Sierra now. If you decide to do below changes you need to know "Uploading App Store with beta software" not allowed by Apple. Continue with El Capitan and Xcode 7.3.1 for production.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the slow solution, you can reinstall Xcode 7.3.1 by downloading it from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.

It worked for me and now my Simulator is able to start again without getting the error.

The issue is discussed in depth here:
[How to fix Xcode "DTAssetProviderService could not start.." error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828996/how-to-fix-xcode-dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-error/37874395#37874395)

Comment: Solution takes a time, but It helps me to be fast in every workflow. Thanks It works without an error.

Comment: This didn't work for me :( I've deleted Xcode 7.3.1 but ALL my preferences and devices are never reset and the Simulator doesn't work no matter what. Any idea of how to "permanently" reset Xcode?

Comment: @MihaiFratu I would also delete `$HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and ensure `xcode-select -p` points to XCode 7.3.1

Comment: @MihaiFratu Did you select **Xcode > Preferences.. > Locations: Command Line Tools: Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014)** ?

Comment: Reinstalling xcode 7.3.1 did the trick and now everything is fine.

Comment: @PeterTheill I did as you said, cleared derivedData and can also confirm that Xcode-select-p points to 7.3.1.

Comment: I downloaded and installed via the App Store, linked to the App Store developer.apple.com/downloads, did you actually download the dmg somehow and install that instead?

Comment: @YichenBman Did you try downloading from Apple's downloads website, not using App Store?

Comment: Yup, my Xcode location is set right. I've deleted the `DerivedData` folder after I've reinstalled Xcode but still no luck. I think I'll roll back to El Capitan soon 'cause I've been stuck for 3 days now :(

Comment: @MihaiFratu Could you try deleting all of them? Please check these paths. Probably help pure uninstalling. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33812614/6135652

Comment: I've already given up and reverted back to OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.3.2. It's the last time I install a beta version :) But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a major bug. Until Apple fixes it, you can work around it:

- Build app
- The app will still install on the simulator, even with the error
- Launch the app manually on the simulator
- Go to Xcode
- Click Debug > Attach to Process > Your App Name

That will enable Xcode debugging features and allow your app to run in simulator. Definitely not ideal, but hopefully you can use this until a real solution comes out.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I have marked pure loading way as an answer. It keeps your workflow stability.

Comment: No problem, that solution is definitely better to keep your workflow fast. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

This is a regression in macOS Sierra that multiple developers have reported in the forums and in the lab sessions at WWDC.  Xcode 7.3 is not supported on Sierra.  If you want to use macOS Sierra, please use Xcode 8.0 beta or later.

If you must use Xcode 7.3 on Sierra, you can partially workaround this bug by using Xcode.app to install the app through Build & Run, launch the app suspended from the command line (`xcrun simctl launch -w booted <app identifier>`) and then attach with the debugger and resume the suspended process.

Note that this issue only impact Xcode 7.3.1 downloaded from the Mac App Store.  You will not hit this issue if you use Xcode downloaded from http://developer.apple.com (ie, the "drag & drop installer").  Note that you *might* hit another issue with the same symptoms when using the drag & drop installer.  That is discussed in [DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator)

Comment: Sorry, not at all.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I've edited my answer to hopefully make it more clear for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already solved with reinstalling Xcode 7.3.1 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: Xcode 8.0 won't run the simulator at all. It says it cannot find the Simulator pid. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Mihai, open a new question, or better yet, file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com.  We have heard no reports of that issue.  Please include a sysdiagnose taken soon after reproducing as well as a tarball of ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator

Answer (score 3):

You can still run the debugger, but you have to attach it manually.

You can run your app tapping the icon in the simulator, than switch back to Xcode and select **Debug**, **Attach to Process** and pick your app process.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps fixed the issue for me:

1. Remove both Xcode 7.3.1 and 8 Beta
2. Remove /Library/Developer and ~/Library/Developer (before removing check the contents and back up whatever you need)
3. Download the Xcode 7.3.1 DMG file and the Xcode 8 Beta xip file (unless you already have them)
4. Install 7.3.1 and test the Simulator (should work fine now)
5. Install 8 Beta and test the Simulator in 7.3.1 again (should work as before)
6. Restore what you backed up on step 2