# Unable to app run on my simulator: macOS Sierra

Tags: ios, macos, debugging, xcode7, beta

I am unable to launch my app on simulator using Xcode 7.3.1  iPhone 5s simulator. I am getting an error message in Xcode is  "DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection"[image]

Comment: And what did the system log tell you?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828996/xcode-dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-error-how-fix-this -- maybe mark this as a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Build app
- The app will still install on the simulator, even with the error
- Launch the app manually on the simulator
- Go to Xcode
- Click Debug > Attach to Process > Your App Name