# Running in Xcode 7.3, and macOS v 10.12 Beta. Error `DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator`. How can I solve this?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, macos-sierra

I have Xcode 8 beta and macOS 10.12. I ran project A in Xcode 8 beta. I switched back to 7.3 and got this error.

> Error: DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator 'iPhone 6s Plus'. Check the system log for errors.

No amount of resetting the simulator, quitting simulator, quitting xcode, restarting my macbook, etc will work.

Then I tried various other projects in Xcode 7.3 (none in 8), and all are getting this error.

I have additional problems in Xcode 8 where none of my NSLog statements are printing to the console.

EDIT: I also cannot create brand new projects in Xcode 7.3 and run under macOS 10.12 without getting that error.

EDIT 2: If I create a branch new Single View application, and type `NSLog(@"Hello World!");` into the `viewDidLoad` method, I don't get any logging statement to the console. I just get...

```
2016-06-17 16:20:12.622791 MyApp[6587:98125] Created DB, header sequence number = 252
2016-06-17 16:20:12.623998 MyApp[6587:98131] bundleid: com.lwt.MyApp, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
2016-06-17 16:20:12.636132 MyApp[6587:98131] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEvents, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-06-17 16:20:12.640879 MyApp[6587:98125] Created DB, header sequence number = 252
2016-06-17 16:20:12.642933 MyApp[6587:98125] Created DB, header sequence number = 252
2016-06-17 16:20:12.644489 MyApp[6587:98125] Created DB, header sequence number = 252
2016-06-17 16:20:12.650247 MyApp[6587:98125] Created DB, header sequence number = 252
2016-06-17 16:20:12.688506 MyApp[6587:98125] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-06-17 16:20:12.709064 MyApp[6587:98126] subsystem: com.apple.FrontBoard, category:  Common, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode "DTAssetProviderService could not start.." error, How fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828996/xcode-dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-error-how-fix-this)