# What do these Xcode simulator system errors mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

The Xcode simulator disconnects from Xcode which will no longer show information in the console of Xcode.  Xcode then provided the following error: "DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator 'iPhone 6'. Check the system log for errors."

I've tried quitting and restarting both the simulator and Xcode but still no luck.  Here are the system log errors:

```
Jun 25 15:49:34 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jun 25 15:49:34 Laurences-MBP diagnosticd[8123]: System mode client started - Console (8117) - mode: 0x8
Jun 25 15:49:48 Laurences-MBP sandboxd[10550] ([318]): useractivityd(318) deny mach-lookup com.apple.PowerManagement.control
Jun 25 15:49:53 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jun 25 15:49:53 Laurences-MBP cloudd[10528]: notify name "com.apple.cloudkit.pcs.flushCaches" has been registered 20 times - this may be a leak
Jun 25 15:50:05 Laurences-MBP sandboxd[10550] ([318]): useractivityd(318) deny mach-lookup com.apple.PowerManagement.control
Jun 25 15:50:05 Laurences-MBP syslogd[47]: ASL Sender Statistics
Jun 25 15:50:08 Laurences-MBP sandboxd[10550] ([318]): useractivityd(318) deny mach-lookup com.apple.PowerManagement.control
Jun 25 15:50:11 Laurences-MBP diagnosticd[8123]: System mode client started - Console (8117) - mode: 0x8
Jun 25 15:50:44 Laurences-MBP sandboxd[10550] ([10647]): lsd(10647) System Policy: deny system-privilege 1013
Jun 25 15:51:00 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jun 25 15:51:00 Laurences-MBP DTServiceHub[10677]: DTServiceHub[10677]: [error] 'mach_msg_send' failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (268435459)
Jun 25 15:51:09 Laurences-MBP Xcode[7692]: Xcode[7692]: [error] 'mach_msg_send' failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (268435459)
Jun 25 15:51:09 Laurences-MBP Xcode[7692]: +[DTServiceHubClient localConnectionWithAuthorization:returningServerPid:]: failed to establish connection with DTServiceHub service '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Resources/DTServiceHub'
Jun 25 15:51:09 Laurences-MBP Xcode[7692]: Xcode[7692]: [error] 'mach_msg_send' failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (268435459)
```

Comment: did you tried restarting mac?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes but it didn't work.  I'm running Sierra and the latest Xcode.

Comment: @user6510422 you replied to the wrong person.

Comment: @Haris Yes but restarting the Mac doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode "DTAssetProviderService could not start.." error, How fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828996/xcode-dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-error-how-fix-this)

Answer (score 1):

You're using Xcode 7.3.1 on macOS Sierra Beta which is not supported.  This question has been discussed in more detail in [XCode "DTAssetProviderService could not start.." error, How fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828996/xcode-dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-error-how-fix-this/37874395#37874395)

Use Xcode 8 beta or Xcode 7.3.1 the .dmg image downloaded from the Developer Portal https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ which doesn't exhibit this problem like the Mac App Store version.