# macOS Sierra Public Beta released - Xcode 7 crashes every time

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7, macos-sierra

After new overcome [XCode "DTAssetProviderService could not start.." error, How fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828996/xcode-dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-error-how-fix-this) issue. Yesterday Xcode 7.3.1 on macOS Sierra Public Beta generally crash while build,run process.

What do you think of this status? Is there any new approach to solve this Xcode problems?

Additionally I have updated below:

> Command Line Tools (OS X 10.12) beta for Xcode
>
> macOS Recovery HD Update

Comment: Always use Xcode beta if you wanted to use a beta OS. It's beta, if it's not working, you shouldn't even be surprised and no one can fix it for you.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai, which you are technically correct, I don't see how your rude response is in anyway helpful...

Comment: Sorry if you saw it that way, but I was here to tell the facts. It's just way too many possibilities to see things went wrong with a beta setup, most of the time you have no way to know why and hardly any fix for them. You are free to spend your $50 worth Apple Technical Support to get the same answer from the official channel.

Comment: Up until beta 5, Xcode 7.3.1 worked fine for me on Sierra....but now it's crashing like this